# Dependency Injection and appInjector issue in Angular2 ver.2.0.0-alpha.37

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, inject

I followed the tutorial from Angular2 official site (https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/displaying-data.html) but when I transpile my app.ts in app.js I receive this error:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'appInjector' does not exist in type

I tried to change this example using:

```
import { Injector } from 'angular2/di';
```

but I receive another error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/di'.

My app structure is:

```
testApp
   node_modules
   src
      typings
      app.js
      app.js.map
      app.ts
      tsconfig.json
      tsd.json
   index.html
   package.json
```

Comment: `appInjector` is now `bindings`. The tutorial is old and outdated. See the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807759/angular2-inject-a-service-to-component-not-working-with-appinject.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks you so much! Now it works! Where I can find these informations in future?

Comment: The best place to look right now is the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: However, things are moving fast. They just now are talking about renaming `bindings` to `providers` ([reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4416)).

Comment: Thanks you! I will follow them!